# Custom UITextView caret in wrong place

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have implemented the syntax text highlighting as given in the question here ([UITextView w/ Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638752/uitextview-w-syntax-highlighting/12666358#12666358)) - it's a great utility and works well when compared to some non-regex versions (such as the example documented here: http://www.a-coding.com/2012/03/syntax-highlighting-in-ios.html).\

Both implementations, however, give me the same issue. When text in the UITextView is automatically wraps (i.e. is longer than the current view allows) the placement of the caret when editing is incorrect - you attempt to start an edit and the caret appears in the wrong place and when you type the text you enter appears further up the text view than you would expect.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to where the issue might be occurring and how I might be able to begin fixing it? Thanks in advance to any input / suggestions.

You can see here that I have typed XXX at the caret but it has appeared further back along the line incorrectly https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUIhd.png

**UPDATE**: The issue seems to be firmly within the fact that the custom UITextView wraps (line breaks) in a different place than the standard Apple UITextView - I'm not sure why this is happening or what to do about it though.

Comment: Another update: this appears to be a generic issue with overlaying some core text on a uitextview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a super answer but with the release of iOS7 this probably isn't how you'd do this now anyway, see a tutorial such as this one: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial